# Owned Type in EF Core with optional navigation

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

Below are My class

```
class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
   
    public int? CityId { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
  
     public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}


public class City
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

My question is:

1. Can i make Address class as OwnedType  because City id is optional
2. if i make Address as owned type then my City class also need to be owned type?

Thanks in advance a. using ef core 3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `Address` class as OwnedType like this.

Adress class:

```
public class Address
{
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public int? CityId { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Company Class:

```
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }     
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

Fluent Api:

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    public YourDbContext (DbContextOptions<YourDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    //Note:no need add Address DbSet

    public DbSet<City> City { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Company> Company { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().OwnsOne(c => c.Address);
    }
}
```

> if i make Address as owned type then my City class also need to be owned type?

Your City class don't need to be owned type.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/owned-entities#explicit-configuration

Result:

When you configure owned type,this make `company` and `address` generate one table and the city id could either be set or not.And if you want to set the city id,you need to insert a new record in your `city` table.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks...cityid is optional in address..can I make address as owned type rite?

Comment: Hi,Did you mean cityid could either be set or not set?

Comment: Yes..cityid is optional  (some companies may not have city ) in address.

Comment: Actually,what i did is make your requirement come true.Check my explanation.Be sure if you use owned type.The Address class cannot have a DbSet<>.

Comment: I don't know what I am missing, I can't get this to work.